# Codemagic ios deployment : Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce "xxxxx"

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to deploy my app to the Apple Store using Codemagic since I don't have a Macbook

I'm having a problem as you can see in the screenshot

thank you for helping me

[image]

error message : Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'

Comment: have you checked this solution? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890